# native android not connecting to socket.io

Tags: android, node.js, kotlin, server, socket.io

I am trying to connect my server deployed in heroko. But as you can see in the code below, i can't connect to my server. I tried it in web (with just html,javascript) and i am able to connect.

But in android using kotlin, i can't connect. I tried adding android:usesCleartextTraffic but doesn't work. Did anyone faced this issue ?

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
private val TAG = "mytag"
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val socket = IO.socket("https://nesib-api.herokuapp.com/")
    socket.connect()

    Log.d(TAG, "socked connected : "+ socket.connected()) //  always returns false
    socket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT){
        Log.d(TAG, "connected ! ") // this method never fires
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Have you declared the `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` in your *AndroidManifest.xml*?

Comment: yes i did that ( in this server i have also rest api, if i go to /todos route and i can get the data with retrofit, but only socket does not work)

Answer (score -1):

Write `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` in your **AndroidManifest.xml**.